# pytest unicode syntaxerror with '£' symbol

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest, python-3.5

I have a test file: `test_pytest.py`:

```
def test_pytest():
    s = '£'
    assert True
```

Using pytest, I run it like this: `python -m pytest test_pytest.py`

The result:

```
> python -m pytest test_pytest.py
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.5.2, pytest-2.9.2, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.3.1
rootdir: c:\temp, inifile:
collected 0 items / 1 errors

=================================== ERRORS ====================================
_______________________ ERROR collecting test_pytest.py _______________________
c:\projects\aio-rpc\venv\lib\site-packages\_pytest\python.py:611: in _importtestmodule
    mod = self.fspath.pyimport(ensuresyspath=importmode)
c:\projects\aio-rpc\venv\lib\site-packages\py\_path\local.py:650: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
E     File "c:\temp\test_pytest.py", line 3
E   SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa3 in position 0: invalid start byte
=========================== 1 error in 0.07 seconds ===========================
```

What gives?

Note that commenting the `s='£'` allows the test to pass

Comment: sometimes hidden characters are not copied to SO, could you try copy-pasting the code posted here back into your test file and see if it still produces the error?

Comment: It does indeed, I tried copying with vim and notepad. I guess you can't reproduce it at your end?

Comment: No, sorry I'm especially confused that commenting it out fixes a `SyntaxError`.

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, my Vim was saving the file with latin1 encoding instead of utf-8. Changing the encoding of the file to utf-8 fixed the problem.